# Redirect after POST request to another HTML document

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, authentication

I have an issue. I'm working on a Login API from a project of the university. So here is the thing.
I have a form where the user put his email and password, and what I want is : If the answer is correct, that is, status 200, it will redirect me to another HTML document inside the project, which in this case is called "home.html".
So I checked from the Client side the response is correct, and the data travel succesfully but although I read several posts I can not give the solution. I am going to attach the HTML code, JS (Front-side) (I'm using Vainilla JS), Server of NodeJS with Express, and the code of the POST request.

**HTML FORM**

```
        <form action="/user/login" method="POST" id="form"> 
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email" class="etiqueta">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="emai" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingresa tu Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="etiqueta">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="boton-inicia" class="btn btn-primary">Inicia Sesion</button>
      </form>
```

**JS Front**

```
    // Funcion de envio
iniciaSesion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Declaro la constante
    const host = 'http://localhost:3000/user/login';

    // Declaro una constante que va a obtener los valores de los inputs
    const form = {
        email: document.getElementById("email").value,
        password: document.getElementById("password").value
    };

    if (form.email === '', form.password === ''){
        UI.mostrarAlerta('Por favor, ingrese todos los datos', 'danger');
    } else { 
        // Declaro su end-point, metodo + envio en JSON
        fetch(host, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(form),
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
        }).then((response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            return response.text();
        }).then((info) => {
            const json = JSON.parse(info)
            // console.log(json);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
};

// Llamo al boton y le agrego su evento y defino la funcion
document.getElementById("boton-inicia").addEventListener('click', iniciaSesion);
```

**Node / Express Server**

```
// Modulos requeridos
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const connectWithMongo = require("./config/db"); // Llamo a la configuracion de conexion a la DB
const user = require("./routes/user"); // Llamo al modelo de usuarios

// Inicios
connectWithMongo();
const app = express();
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, "../public/");

// Declaro puerto para el servidor 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

//Middleware
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

// Con esta peticion, chequeo que la API este funcionando
app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "Api Running"
    });
});

app.use("/user", user);

app.listen(PORT, (req,res) => {
    console.log(`Server iniciado en puerto ${PORT}`);
});
```

**POST Method**

```
router.post("/login", [
    // Le indico los inputs a chequear
     check("email", "Por favor, ingrese un email").isEmail(),
     check("password", "Por favor, ingrese una contraseña").isLength({min: 6})
 ], async (req, res) => {
    // Requiero la data
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        // Declaro en una variable que busque a un usuario por email si existe
        let user = await User.findOne({
            email
        });

        // Declaro que, si el email es distinto, devuelva un mensaje
        if (!user)
        return res.status(401).json ({
            message: "Usuario no existe"
        });

        // Constante que va a comparar email con contraseña
        const esIgual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        // Declaro que, si el email es distinto, devuelva un mensaje
        if (!esIgual)
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Contraseña no coincide"
        });

        const payload = {
            user: {
                id: user.id
            }
        };

        jwt.sign(payload,"randomString", {
            expiresIn: 10000
        }, (err, token) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.status(200).json({
                    token
                });
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Error de servidor"
        });
    }
 });
```

Thanks for all !

PD: I'm attaching a caption from the console of the browser, where you can see, I have the token from the authentication and the status of the response.
[Click here to see it !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcwEY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're submitting the form via JavaScript you can use `window.location.replace()` after successful call:

```
fetch(host, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(form), 
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
}).then((response) => {
  // console.log(response);
  return response.text();
}).then((info) => {
  const json = JSON.parse(info)
   window.location.replace("/home.html"); // <= HERE
  // console.log(json);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
})
```

Also, you can read `json` response directly without doing `text()` and `JSON.parse`:

```
fetch(host, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(form),
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
   // do stuff with `json` body
   window.location.replace("/home.html"); // <= HERE
})
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Hello Sam ! Thanks for your answer, that method works, but for some reason it does not perform the validation.
For example, I put the email and a password different from the one registered and it redirects me anyway and that should not happen

Comment: @FedeBerbara, so `bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);` always returns `true` even if you use a different password?

Comment: I know, sounds weird right ? `bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);` if working, because I tested in the browser and in Postman and if a put a diferent password I recive the message : Incorrect Password. 

I'm still fighting with this problem :'(